# How to implement Roll-Up logic in declarative way for formula fields with references to other objects

Tags: trigger, formula, process-builder, roll-up-summary

I have two objects:

1. DPA Pay Line - custom object

   Fields:

   a. Bill To Account - formula field with references to other lookup objects

   b. DPA Record - Master-Detail to DPA object
2. DPA - custom object

   Fields:

   a. Summary Bill To Account - should have a sum of all "Bill To Account" fields from all related "DPA Pay Line" records.

---

- Roll-Up Summary field in DPA object does not work for this case, because of external references from the formula field.
- I tried Process Builder on "Bill To Account" field of "DPA Pay Line" object to copy value to Currency field in "DPA Pay Line" object, and then Roll-Up Summary field on that currency field in DPA object. However, process does not detect when the formula field is changed in "DPA Pay Line" object and does not update currency field until I edit the object manually (edit->save).
- I researched also on how to implement it using two processes from Process Builder calling each other. One process probably calculating the sum in DPA object, and another process triggering the sum calculation process when Bill To Account is changed. But I could not figure how to define such two processes.

Is it possible to do without coding a trigger?

Comment: Declarative lookup rollup summaries

Comment: Do you mean Roll-Up Summary field? It will not work in this case.

Comment: Nope, Eric meant [Andrew Fawcett's Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary tool](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries). It uses triggers in the back-end, but it provides a declarative interface for you to use.

Comment: It is probably the best solution. Except that Realtime works well when Child object is Edited. However, if formula field change value due to external changes, the Rollup will not recalculate. It could be good to have an option of Calculate button for parent object.